# Regular expressions convert PCRE to POSIX to use regex in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, regex

I have this PCRE regex: (this regex with example on RegExr http://regexr.com/39lbb )

```
/(?=.*?ben)(?=.*?john).*/ig
```

And i have this PCRE regex: (this regex with example on RegExr http://regexr.com/39lbh )

```
/.*?\b(john|ben)\b.*/ig
```

How can i convert this PCRE regex to POSIX or how can i create same POSIX regex? I want use this regex in my MySQL query ( REGEXP http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html )

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the look-ahead and non-greedy matching, you don't need any of it.

```
[[:<:]](john|ben)[[:>:]]
```

Note that `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` start-of-word and end-of-word boundaries, respectively (`\b` is both).

I also suspect you want to *find* strings that contain the words `'ben'` or `'john'`, not *match their contents*, so I assume the `.*` is superfluous as well.

Comment: "Not working" is not an error description. Do you see an error message? If yes, which one? If no, what happens? Also, you did not clarify what the expression *is suppoesed to* do.

Comment: PS: Of course the regex delimiters (forward slashes) are not recognized in MySQL.

Comment: Yes, but in you example, i doing the same as in my second regex, but how i can select only if mathes "John" and "Ben" ? For example, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fbbd/2/0 , but there selected all where contains one of values in parentheses ...

Comment: In my example on sqlfiddle i want get only "Tom", because only `Tom` contains `Moscow` and `Paris`.

Comment: Regular expressions do not work this way. `"[[:<:]](MOSCOW|PARIS)[[:>:]]"` means *"contains either `'MOSCOW'` **or** `'PARIS'`"*, and that's exactly what you get. If you want exact matches, work with `=`. If you want to match *both* `'MOSCOW'` **and** `'PARIS'`", you do two separate matches: `WHERE Place RLIKE "[[:<:]]MOSCOW[[:>:]]" AND Place RLIKE "[[:<:]]PARIS[[:>:]]"`. Final word, it's your fault if you have built a database against fundamental relational principles. You are not supposed to have lists of values in a single field, normalize your DB properly and your problems are gone.